# Can't seem to read a tar.gz file correctly into Python

Tags: python, numpy, file-io

I've downloaded a tar.gz file from this site:

http://www.vision.caltech.edu/Image_Datasets/Caltech101/

It's supposed to contain many images.
Ideally, I would like to read all the images into a huge np.array in their
original dimensions.

Here is one of my attempts:

```
import tarfile
import numpy as np 


images = []

with tarfile.open(file, "r:gz") as tar:

    for member in tar.getmembers()[:10]:
         if  member.isfile():
              file=tar.extractfile(member)
              image.append(file.read())
```

Now file.read() returns class 'bytes' ; not sure how to read that into an
numpy array.

I've tried

```
np.array(file.read())  # ValueError: embedded null byte
np.fromfile(file)   # AttributeError: '_FileInFile' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [NP.fromstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html):

```
NP.fromstring(file.read(), dtype=NP.uint8)
```

If you want the bytes encoded as 8 bit unsigned integers.  You can change the dtype if you want something else.

Edit: I changed 32 bit to 8 bit.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, I get a Value error as follows:
`ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size`

Comment: I edited my answer.  I think you want to use uint8 rather than uint32.  The latter expects the size to be a multiple of 4